# How do I delete all content for a given facet?

Tags: c#, algolia

I'm trying to delete content from my Aloglia index in the C# api.

I can't seem to find any examples online that show how facets work.

Before I attempt a DeleteByQuery command I was trying to get a search with the same criteria working.

```
AlgoliaClient searchClient = new AlgoliaClient("xxx", "xxx");
Index purgeIndex = searchClient.InitIndex("MyTestIndex");
Query purgeQuery = new Query("");
JArray facetFilters = new JArray("versions", "6.12.2");
purgeQuery.SetFacetFilters(facetFilters);
JObject res = purgeIndex.Search(purgeQuery);
```

But the res object is undefined when I run this code.

Am I even close?  Once I know the filtering is working I can then pass the same query into the delete function.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working.

Here is the syntax in case anyone else needs to delete all index content for a given facet.

```
AlgoliaClient searchClient = new AlgoliaClient("x", "x");
Index purgeIndex = searchClient.InitIndex(paramIndex);
Query purgeQuery = new Query("");
JArray facetFilters = new JArray();
JToken facetToken = JToken.Parse("['" + paramFacetName + ":" + paramFacetValue + "']");
facetFilters.Add(facetToken);
purgeQuery.SetFacetFilters(facetFilters);
purgeIndex.DeleteByQuery(purgeQuery);
```